# How can I change a button from going to the next page to doing some code?

Tags: html, button

I am new to perl/html. This is from a perl file. This button is in there right now:

```
<button id = "button1" name = "submitButton" type="submit">
       <span class="right">Submit</span>
</button>
```

I don't see any piece of code where submitButton or button1 is given any logic so I don't understand why this jumps to the next page. Can someone explain?

EDIT: This seems to be the only javascript in the whole file...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  % $m->comp('../js/share.js');
  </script>
```

I looked at the file, and it doesn't seem to do any redirecting or anything.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl, this is 100% HTML.

Comment: Hi, Jeremy. Is there any javascript code mentioned in the header of the html? If so, please post it.

Comment: You can make it type="button" and it won't post (change the page).  Then you can add javascript code to the onclick="function()" attribute

Comment: Clicking a submit button will submit the page automatically. Find the FORM element which contains this button - its `action` attribute tells you which Perl script is called....

Comment: What are pages there? What perl file contains? Can you explain problem more clearly?

Comment: @Sydenam That's interesting. How can I then simulate a "submit" later in the JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a submit button, it does the logic defined by the Form that surrounds it.

Answer (score 0):

Often event handlers are hooked up at run-time using JavaScript. If there is an included script, look in the code for "button1" and see which function is hooking it up.

Also since this is a SUBMIT button, if it is wrapped in a form, no code needs to hook this up. It will post to whatever is defined in the form's `ACTION` property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some JS/Jquery or another js-framework included to the page?